# How to tell if refund was issued via API or through the regular web interface?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is there anyway to know if the refund was issued directly from PayPal web ui or via API (of some kind)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't one that I know of. They show up in the website and API the same way.

This is why I log all my API calls. Makes it easier to find out what your API calls have done.

Answer (score 1):

While performing the refund thru API or PayPal account you can make use of the "note" field which will be displayed on the Transaction detail page . So you can pass the different text( some standard text ) while performing refund through API and different text while doing from PayPal account .
In this way you can differentiate between two types of refunds.